# Powershell Exit Python Environment

Tags: python, powershell

I can exit a python 3 environment in powershell easily using <kbd>Control c</kbd> which  gives

```
>>> ^Z
```

and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> to exit.

If I instead type or paste `^Z` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> I get:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the difference?

Shouldn't text be treated the same regardless of how it's entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, Python interprets it as a Substitute Character. This character is used by Python to denote the end of file. Python represents the substitute character by using `^Z` because in many environments <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> can be used to send this character.

However, when you paste `^Z` into python and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it does not exit. This is because when python reads `^Z` it gets three bytes, `0x5e 0x5a 0x0a`, which represent `^`, `Z` and New Line respectively. When you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, Python gets only one byte, `0x1a`, which represents the substitute character. Since the values are not the same, Python does not interpret them as the same.

The same result occurs with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> because this signals python to close. The way Python closes itself is by sending itself the substitute character, which is why you see `^Z` on the command line.